# UK Ancestry visa - what is 'UK Sponsor' that dependents have to supply?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, ancestry-visas

I applying for a UK Ancestry visa and my wife is also applying. The official immigration channel has advised us to apply for the following visas:

**Main applicant**

- Reason for visit- Work
- Visa type: Non- Point based working visa
- Visa sub-type – UK Ancestry

**Dependent**

- Reason for Visit: Work
- Visa type: Non Points-Based Visas
- Visa subtype: Dependants 6 months or more

My question is that when my wife is completing her application as the dependent there is a section asking for her UK Sponsor. What should she put for this? There is no requirement for her to have a job in the UK as part of this visa yet this appears to be what it is asking for.

Below are the images showing the UK sponsor screen, then the individual pop ups for the person and the organisation.

Any advice on what to put on these would be greatly appreciated.

**UK Sponsor Section**

[image: UK Sponsor section]

**Sponsor person details pop up**

[image]

**Sponsor organisation details pop up**

[image]

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something - aren’t you the sponsor? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576708/UK-Ancestry-v16.pdf

Comment: I was initially thinking that, but I don't fit any of the options in the 'status' dropdown option in the second image, and I don't have an organisation either.

Comment: In that case, are you sure that ‘work’ is the correct reason for visit choice for your wife?

Comment: Yes, she intends to work, and the UK Ancestry Visa allows her to enjoy the same conditions I will get.